# Path.GetTempPath in mobile devices

Tags: c#, mobile

I'm using `Path.GetTempPath()` in our website, create a folder in it and will serve as the path where the email attachments of the user will be uploaded and will be deleted after the email was sent.

Our website is not published yet so haven't tried if it will work in mobile devices? Will this work in mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

There is no temp folder in mobiles, so you need to create the folder at Isolated storage. Here is the link to create Isolated storage in windows phone.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.createdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

Similar isolated storage is present in different phone OS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)